# C# SqlConnection inside a loop

Tags: c#, loops, sqlconnection

first time on stackoverflow.
I'm learning how to manage SqlConnection in my WebForm pages, and I want to reach the best practice to do that.
In my specific case, I have a loop and there's no way for me to run the code without errors if I don't set a new SqlConnection for every iteration of the loop (the error is about an attempt to read when reader is close).
So I declare this in the PageLoad method:

```
private SqlConnection con;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

Then I have this:

```
private int conta(int padre)
{
    string SQL = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE idp=@idpadre";
    SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
    cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idpadre", padre);
    int sub=0;
    try
    {                
        if ((con.State & ConnectionState.Open) <= 0)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                sub++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lbl.Text = "Errore conta!";
        lbl.Text += err.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();

    }
    return sub;
}

protected void buildParent(int padre, int level)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
    }
    sb.Append("|--");
    selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE idp=@idpadre";
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idpadre", padre);

    try
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (read.Read())
            {

                dlParent.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = sb.ToString() + read["cat"].ToString(), Value = read["idcat"].ToString() });
                int sub = conta(Convert.ToInt32(read["idcat"]));
                //int sub = 0;
                if (sub > 0)
                {
                    buildParent(Convert.ToInt32(read["idcat"]), level + 1);
                }

            }
            read.Close();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lbl.Text = "Errore buildParent!";
        lbl.Text += err.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
        if (s != null)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                buildPage();
                buildLang();
                buildImage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In buildParent in the while loop i call "conta", but if I use the same SqlConnection (con) with both the methods I have an error about an attempt to read when reader is close.
I'm worried about the connection pool on the web server, particularly concerning the max connection reach.
So, where am I wrong? What's the best practice to manage SqlConnection?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You open the connection as late as possible, and you dispose as soon as possible. Let the [connection pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) deal with reclaiming the connections.

I usually write my code like this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandToRun, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[]
        {
            new SqlParameter("myParam", "myvalue"),
            new SqlParameter("myParam", "myvalue")
        });

    conn.Open(); // opened as late as possible
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // do stuff.
        }
    }
} // disposed here.
```

Note: To get a count from a SQL database you better use

```
SELECT count(*) FROM categories WHERE idp=@idpadre
```

And execute the query with `ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Also, when you are done, make sure you dispose the connection.  IT doesn't look like that's happening now.

Comment: It is, in the `finally` block.

Comment: but it's correct to create a different sqlconnection object in the loop? and when I close the connection, I have to dispose it also?

Comment: @FabioGarzoli yes, look at the link i added to the post. Behind the scenes .NET is leaving the connection open even though you disposed the connection and will re-use the connection instead of creating a new one if a timeout has not expired. (also if you dispose the connection you do not need to close it, as that will close the connection as part of the disposing process)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the link, I'll study it. In a simple way I need to change con.Close(); in con.Dispose(); and I'm fine and sure that the connection pool max size is not reached, am I right? Another question: is there a way to check in Visual Studio (I'm using Visual Web Developer) how many connections are opened?

Comment: @FabioGarzoli Not in any GUI of Visual Studio, but the if you do the query `exec sp_who2` in SQL it will return a result showing all the connections to the server

Comment: Well, I have some code that calls multiple methods from a loop. The connections are opened and closed correctly by each method. In theory, closed connections just go back to the pool. I have ran into situations where a slow query in a loop causes a new connection to be grabbed from the pool, maxing out the connections and taking down the site. The solution for me was to open one connection outside the loop and pass this one open connection to each of the methods. When it is done looping, the connection is then closed/disposed. Doing this stopped the max connections site crashes for me.

Comment: You should deal with this by tweaking the "Max Pool Size", the "ConnectRetryCount" and the "ConnectRetryInterval" connections tring parameters.